# Live USB now asks for log in after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: usb, live-usb

I have a Mint live USB which I've used for ages and worked fine when I ran Ubuntu 18.04 on my PC. I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 a couple of weeks ago and today needed a live boot to re-partition. Using the live USB I've used for ages it now wants a user name and password. The only thing that's changed is Ubuntu (host OS) from 18.04 to 20.04, so is there some security setting in the latest LTS requiring a username and password? (I doubt it as the host OS surely isn't loading when booting from a USB) I've tried it blank and with my Ubuntu credentials but no joy. I've booted many flavours of Live USB in the past and never been asked to log in.

Yes, I could create another live USB of Ubuntu, but I'm confused as to why this Mint one worked fine up until now...

Thanks

Comment: LiveUSBs are read-only (squashfs), which makes them extremely difficult to change -- impossible for most folks without great effort. We do not answer questions about Mint LiveUSBs -- great question for Mint support, though.

Comment: Yeah I guessed that. So why is it now asking for a log in after I've upgraded to 20.04? It worked no problem before.

Comment: We do not answer questions about Mint LiveUSBs

Comment: It's not a question about Mint! It's clearly a question about whether upgrading to UBUNTU 20.04 can affect live USBs...

Comment: Of course not. LiveUSBs are read-only (squashfs).

Comment: @Roger06, Are you talking about a live (live-only) or *persistent* live system? We can expect many strange things to happen if you attempt to upgrade a Linux Mint system to an Ubuntu system. But it is another thing if you overwrite the Mint system with an Ubuntu system for example by cloning from an Ubuntu iso file. And then we would be able to understand what should happen and also help you. Please explain with details, what you have created, what kind of system that you have now on your USB drive.

Comment: @user535733 As  Sudodus says above, there are *Live USB's* and there are *Persistent Live USB's*. They are both Live USB's.

Comment: I have occasionally had Persistent Live USB's start asking for a password when persistence has gotten close to being full. It happened again this week with an Ubuntu Persistent USB, I deleted a few things from casper-rw partition and ran `fsck` and everything is now okay.